# Vagrant does not see VirtualBox provider

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Problem:  Running vagrant results in:

> No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Running `vagrant up --provider virtualbox` or `--provider VirtualBox` or `--provider=VirtualBox` does not alter the error message (no specific issues - just the same generic message).

Starting VirtualBox manually works fine.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and installed VirtualBox 5.2.6 by adding to */etc/apt/sources.list*:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian artful contrib
```

and running `apt-get install virtualbox-5.2`

Got Vagrant 1.9.1 directly from the .deb package download.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 2):

.. and I solved it.  Looks like 5.2 is not supported for some reason.

```
apt-get remove virtualbox-5.2
apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

starting vagrant now works well.